# Make a post request and send info to the reactjs file

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm setting up a website in reactJS and a server in NodeJS. I have a form that i want to use to post data to the node server.

Here is my react js form :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './app.css';
import Header from './header/Header.js';
import Footer from './footer/Footer.js';



export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>https://github.com/crsandeep/simple-react-full-stack</h1>
                <Header />
                <form action="localhost:8080/login" method="post" name="login">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Choix du serveur</legend>
                        <label>IP baie : </label>
                        <input name="IP" id="IP" type="text" required />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <label>user baie : </label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="3paradm" name="user" id="userbaie" onChange={this.handleUserNameChange} required />
                        <label>Password baie : </label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="PWbaie" required />
                        <br />
                        <input type="submit" defaultValue="Submit" />
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
                <Footer />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const os = require('os');
const path = require("path");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static('dist'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post("/login", (request, response) => {
    var IP = request.body.IP;
    var user = request.body.user;
    var password = request.body.password;
    const testscript = exec('python getCPG.py ' + IP + ' ' + user + ' ' + password);
    testscript.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${process.env.PORT || 8080}!`));
```

I use the same technique that I was used to with HTML5. But it doesn't work.

I want my website to complete the post request and send the info to the server. When the submit button is finished, it must redirect to another page with informations that will be sent from the node server.

Thank you for your help

Comment: `action="/login"` give your node js url for the action in the form

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Isn't this the way to get it?

Comment: run your node server. then paste server's url into the form action

Comment: I edited the question with the correction but doesn't seem to do anything when clicking on the button submit.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add the submit url as the nodejs server url.
You have added react app url in the form

`<form action="/replaceThisWithyourServerUrl" method="post" name="login">`

1. Run react app lets say its running on port 3000
2. Then run the node js app let say its running on port 3001

then the action url would be `action='http://locahost:3001/login'`

And you have to respond with appropriate response in the method

```
app.post("/login", (request, response) => {
    var IP = request.body.IP;
    var user = request.body.user;
    var password = request.body.password;
    // please implement your logic after this line
    // Im simply showing you how to send the response back to the user
    return response.status(200).json({success: true, message: 'logged in'})

});
```

Comment: So in my case it would be : <form action="localhost:8080/login" method="post" name="login">. I did that but the submit button doesn't do anything afterwards

Comment: I edited the question with the correction but doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: please send the response as above to the user

Comment: it doesn't do anything sadly.

Comment: then there should be a problem with your `testscript.stdout` line. you can implement as above. later implement your logic

Comment: the problem must be elsewhere then because even when taking off ```testscript.stdout``` it doesn't do anything

Comment: nop, it does'n't do anything. when i press submit on my webpage, nothing happens.